# How Do I Make 3D Objects in CSS

Tags: html, css, 3d, transform, transition

I've been trying to create a rectangular prism as indicated from here:

(example) http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/box-02-show-sides.html

There's also a tutorial page.
but these are my results,

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qFdiu

I don't know what is wrong here.. sometimes when I check a preview in chrome, it will animate, but not in the right place, the prism won't be in its container and it won't transform on the correct origin, i.e. like flipping a block on the floor it will move over, instead of being in its original place but on a different face. I've even tried copying everything from the tutorial but can't find out the fault. I am pretty new to webdesign. Would appreciate any help :)